# Slide 2 Div with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My target is make 2 divs and slide between them with buttons . also i need the focus one get The main ID  So my code was :

HTML :

```
<button type="button" class="go">go</button>
<button type="button" class="back">back</button>

<div class="Wrapper">
    <div class="Main" id="mainID">Main Content</div>
     <div class="info">The Sympol kyes</div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".show").click(function(){
    $('.Main').animate({right :'-300px'},500);
    $('.info').animate({left:'0px'},500);
});

$(".back").click(function(){
    $('.info').animate({left :'-300px'},500);
    $('.Main').animate({right:'0px'},500);
});
```

Olease check the Live [Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgzLzZ)

- the issue is when i press close its back very slow :(
- and how the focus div take the id="mainID"

Comment: Your Fiddle and the code you provided here do not match!!

Comment: wrong fiddle. What css code are you applying ?

Comment: There is No class called in code show it should be $(".go").click(function(){})

Comment: @AirnCool , @ Asit Vachhan , sorry file updated

Comment: jquery not supported on this example site.

Comment: @ Asit Vachhan Its updated now :S